# Prevent Duplicate Post Counted by Query

Tags: wp-query, loop, duplicates, post-duplication

```
<?php 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    
    $get_series_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'series_seri', true );
    
    if (in_array($get_series_id, $do_not_duplicate)) {
            continue; // We've already seen this post ID, so skip the rest of the loop
        }
    
$do_not_duplicate[] = $get_series_id;
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

how to make duplicate post not counted ? i wanna show 20 post, but in frontpage only showing 5 post because duplicate post also counted,

Comment: Where you're defining duplicate by your series_seri post meta? WordPress's main query doesn't know anything about that, so I think you'd have to going to have to write your own SQL for that: maybe a subquery to find the most recent post per series and then take the top 20 of those. By doing the filtering in PHP the database won't know how many records it needs to give you to get the 20 distinct, so you'll either have to put the logic in the database or keep fetching more records here until you get your 20 distinct.

Comment: Alternatively you could pre-compute the filtered list and store it as a transient: fetch all the posts in PHP, do the series_seri filtering and then save the list of post IDs in order to a transient, and then you can page through that list. You'd need to add hooks to clear or rebuild the transient on new posts or post meta updates for series_seri.

Comment: Are you using `query_posts`? I can't see where/if you're making queries in your code

Comment: just using default wordpress general setting to limit front page total post to 20,
also already try add query_posts("showposts=20");